# Turn a python windows path into a regular path for JSON

Tags: javascript, python, json

I want to turn \\\\Network Share\\Folder\\Folder\\File.jpg into a regular path - \\Network Share\Folder\Folder\File.jpg - for a JSON string that I am passing to JavaScript. My code is:

```
def searchFile(fileName):
    for entry in os.scandir(folderToSearch):
        if fileName.upper() in entry.path.upper():
            if entry.is_file():
                return entry.path
```

Which is returning with the extra backslashes. When I read the JSON data in JavaScript, it cannot find the file due to the extra backslashes. How do I transfer the data from Python to JavaScript?

I am using the eel library.

**EDIT**

This is how I am creating my JSON data to pass to JavaScript:

```
def createUserJSON():
    UserData = {}
    JSONData = []
    UserData['fullName'] = "Test User"
    UserData['email'] = "Test.User@test.com"
    UserData['userImage'] = searchFile("TestUser")
    json_data = json.dumps(UserData)
    JSONData.append(json_data)
    return JSONData
```

This then returns:

```
['{"fullName": "Test User", "email": "Test.User@test.com", "userImage": "\\\\Network Share\\Folder\\Folder\\File.jpg"}']
```

Comment: are you sure that it's because of the extra backslashes? have you printed the file from the javascript side? what you're doing from the python side is 100% correct. Isn't there another (security) issue from the JS side?

Comment: the chrome console is showing the extra backslashes in the array - It shows it as ["{"fullName": "Test User", "email": "Test.User@test.com", "userImage": "\\\\Network Share\\Folder\\Folder\\File.jpg"}"]

Comment: yeah, that's the representation of the array, exactly like in python. Have you tried to print the data as string? have you tested a file outside the networked drive?

Comment: It seems you are right, i changed the output path but JavaScript is throwing up the error - maybe eel cannot handle local file loading like electron. Opened a new ticket here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66526446/not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-eel-python/66526486#66526486